# Simple Linked lists implementation in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to print my list more than 3 times..

It should be something like

```
A: 5  B: 2 C: 3
A: 6  B: 4 C: 1
A: 7  B: 3 C: 15
A: 5  B: 2 C: 3
A: 6  B: 4 C: 1
```

but after the 3rd time, it crashes..

Please have a look at my code and show me how to fix it..

PS: Moreover, can I edit the values of the list in the second/third run??

Thanks in advance,,

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    struct list {
            int a,b,c;
            struct list *next;
    };

    struct list *init_list ( int a, int b, int c );
    void list_print( struct list *list );

    struct list *init_list ( int a, int b, int c ){
            struct list *list;
            list = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
            if (list == NULL) {
                    printf("Error: Memory allocation failure.\nTerminating.\n");
                    exit(1);
            }

            list->a = a;
            list->b = b;
            list->c = c;
            list->next = NULL;
            return (list);
    }

    void list_print(struct list *list) {
            int j = 0;
            struct list *list2;
            do {
                            list2 = list;
                            struct list *tmp; 
                            tmp = list;

                            printf("A: %d  B: %d C: %d\n" ,tmp->a, tmp->b, tmp->c);
                            list = list->next;

                            j++;
            } while (j < 4);
    }


    int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        struct list *linked_list_1, *linked_list_2;
        linked_list_1 = init_list(5, 2, 3);
        linked_list_1->next = init_list(6, 4, 1); linked_list_2 = linked_list_1->next;
        linked_list_2->next = init_list(7, 3, 15); 

        list_print(linked_list_1);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you have list1->list2->list3->NULL.
So when j = 0, you print list1, then move to list2. j now equals 1, you print list2 and move to the next element, j = 2 you print again and move to NULL. Trying to print the content of a NULL pointer crashes your program

Comment: What cnicutar said is good, you have to check for the end of the list. If it only prints 3 times, that's because there's no more element in your list. If you want to go back to the first element, make the next pointer of your last element point to your first element. Like: linked_list_2->next->next = linked_list_1

Comment: sorry i wasnt clear enough.. I wanna retrieve the first element when there is nothing more

Answer (score 0):

list2 and tmp are not used at all: although you've assigned list to them.

But the real problem is that you're asking for 4 items from a list when there is only 3. Of course the last one is NULL and causes a crash.

Comment: I want to retrieve the first one